# background request cases a CATransaction error

Tags: ios, uiimage, background-image, nsurlconnection, background-process

I am trying to download image in the background. When I am trying to download it, I receive next error:

+[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

I am trying to download it in cellForRowAtIndexPath of UITableView. I have first encountered with such problem. Thanks in advance. Here is the code for that, it is located in separate file:

```
- (id) initWithImageID: (NSString*) imageID
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
        self.imageID = imageID;

        NotedPreferences* np = [NotedPreferences sharedPreferences];
        NSString* url = [[np apiURL] stringByAppendingFormat: @"/thumbs/%@.jpg", imageID];
        NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: url];

        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = (NSMutableURLRequest*)[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:timeout60];
        [self basicAuthForRequest:theRequest withUsername:@"app" andPassword:@"123"];
        self.theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        CFRunLoopRun();
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)basicAuthForRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request withUsername:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password
{
    CFStringRef usernameRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)username;
    CFStringRef passwordRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)password;

    CFHTTPMessageRef authoriztionMessageRef = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault,    (__bridge CFStringRef)[request HTTPMethod], (__bridge CFURLRef)[request URL], kCFHTTPVersion1_1);

    CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication(authoriztionMessageRef, nil, usernameRef, passwordRef, kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic, FALSE);

    CFStringRef authorizationStringRef = CFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue(authoriztionMessageRef, CFSTR("Authorization"));

    [request setValue:(__bridge NSString *)authorizationStringRef forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    CFRelease(authorizationStringRef);
    CFRelease(authoriztionMessageRef);
}

- (void)connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData: (NSData *) data
{
    [self.receivedData appendData: data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (self.receivedData != nil)
    {
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: self.receivedData];

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestHaveFinishedWithImage:imageID:success:)])
            [self.delegate requestHaveFinishedWithImage:image imageID:self.imageID success: true];
    }

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

- (void)connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError: (NSError *) error
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestHaveFinishedWithImage:imageID:success:)])
        [self.delegate requestHaveFinishedWithImage:nil imageID:self.imageID success: false];

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc of DownloadImageObject");
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what this has to do with the `CATransaction`, but all of this manual `CFRunLoop` stuff doesn't look good. It smells like some old school attempt to run a `NSURLConnection` on a background thread, but you don't show us where you actually initiate the `NSURLConnection` in the background thread, so we can't say. You're not trying to do this from the main thread, though, are you? That would be bad. Also, if you are running this on background thread, is your delegate then dispatching the UI update back to the main thread? So, show us this delegate method, too.

Comment: I have added NSURLConnection object, I forgot to add it. Now everything works, but am I doing it the right way? Maybe calling the delegate method after CFRunLoopStop()?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any of that `CFRunLoop` stuff, IMHO. The only time one is tempted to do that would be if you're starting this request in background thread. You haven't shown us that you're doing anything like that (it's generally not needed as `NSURLConnection` can run asynchronously fine without that complication), and even if you were, I'd be inclined to solve it in any of a number of other ways. You're not showing us, though, how you're calling this object, nor what the delegate is doing, so it's hard for us to advise you further.